# Open and close same class elements on different sections independently

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have posts sections that get populated with data from a database. Here is the markup for the post section. The posts are mostly sample data

```html
<div class="q_posts">
  <div class="q_post_title">
    <span>Post 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="post_description">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, nihil! Eligendi sed voluptate suscipit animi debitis voluptates ducimus, dolorum accusamus?

  </div>
  <a class="link-share-post" title="share a link to this post">Share</a>
  <input type="text" name="link-share-post-input" class="ps_input link-share-an" id="link-share-post-<?php echo $data['post_id']; ?>" value="">
</div>
```

this section is placed in a while loop and is continously rendered on the browser once there is new data in the database.

Now, the `a tag` with `link-share-post` has a `click event` that displays the `input below it, one with the link-share-an class`, **this event works fine, the input is displayed once i click the anchor tag, the problem comes when there is more than one sections of the `q_posts` class, the link in the first section works well, but the one in the second and subsequent sections doesnt**

Here is my javascript

```js
const anLinkShareBtn = document.querySelector(".link-share-post");
const anLinkShareOutput = document.querySelector(".link-share-an");

anLinkShareBtn.addEventListener("click", function showAnLink() {
   anLinkShareOutput.style.display = "block";
   anLinkShareOutput.value = "http://localhost/shareposts/posts";
});
```

i need to be able to open the hidden input once i click on each link independently on the different posts section

Comment: Please share more details. How is this question related to PHP, while it does not contain a single line of PHP code?

Comment: the only relation to php, here is how it helps render the post output sections post class, but stavros angelis answer has helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that you use the **querySelector** to select your elements. querySelector selects the first match in the document tree, meaning that when there are more than one elements with the same class it only works for the first one.

One way to solve this would be to select all elements with this classname (link-share-post) by using the **querySelectorAll**, loop through them and add a click event listener to each one of those elements. Then to select the correct input element you simply need to select the next sibling element. This would look like this:

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".link-share-post");
for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i +=1) {
    const link = links[i];
    link.addEventListener("click", function () {
        link.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";
        link.nextElementSibling.value = "http://localhost/shareposts/posts";
    });
}
```